# A Group That Span A Space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $A=\{x^2,2x+x^2,x+x^3\}$ 
Does $A$ span $\mathbb{R}_3[X]$?

The basis is defined to be that smallest group that span that space, due to the trivial basis which dimension is 4, there is no smaller group that span the space.

Is it a right argument?

Comment: You should use the word set instead of the word group - the reason is that a group is a mathematical object that is different then a set (I can understand the confusion, in my first language the word group can translate into something very similar to a set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is correct - but note that although the number of element
in a basis is minimal the sentence "The basis is defined to be that
smallest group that span that space" is a bit wrong since there
are many sets of minimal cardinality that spans the space and not
only one.

Indeed - if $A$ spans $V$ then $\alpha A:=\{\alpha a\mid a\in A\}$
also spans $V$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}$